# How to transition between 2rooms when gap is wider than standard 2" " t molding strip laminate

Tags: floor, laminate

How can I transition between 2 rooms if gap is wider than standard 2"t molding strip for laminate floor? Looked for wider strip but could not find one.

Comment: They do make wider aluminum, oak. Threshold strips.

Comment: How large is the gap? How wide are the planks you're using?  A photo or two might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you did the flooring & have excess pieces you can cut the flooring to fit in there. If not, then really anything of the same thickness will do with a staining polyurethane combo. If you want an actual & obvious transition because it's a doorway separation sort of thing, then a [Door Threshold](http://www.homedepot.com/s/wood+door+threshold?NCNI-5) might be the best option.